# Need for Merging the Dlls and creating a Single Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, ilmerge

Im trying to deploy a winforms application.Currently i intend to pack the Dlls and Executable into a Single Exe of about 12MB in Size(Compressed).Is this the standard procedure?Is there some downsides for this approach?

Answer (score 6):

Microsoft actually provides a tool for this, called [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx).  Keep in mind:

- You immediately lose any ability to update just one component in your application- you need to repack new versions and ship them as one file.
- It doesn't work for WPF, so it may limit your upgrade path from winforms
- There are better approaches (documented in the link above) for .NET 4.5.

Also, someone created a [GUI](http://ilmergegui.codeplex.com/) for it.

Comment: I know about ILMERGE.Is this the standard procedure-recommended?

Comment: @techno yes, it's pretty standard, though that may change in the future to favor the alternative approach I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some official links and a pretty good list of the Pros and Cons at the end of this thread where the original poster who asked of a similar question summarized feedback and what he learned:

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/single-multiple-assemblies-big-apps-and-code-reuse-t2659572.html

In short, the main drawbacks are difficulty in servicing (deploying new versions of only some functionality), potentially reduced startup time (all code is loaded upfront) and larger memory footprint even when some functionality that is loaded may not be required. The potential benefits I can see are simpler deployment, potentially less overhead for loading assemblies on demand, and possibly better obfuscation of code (with tools) if that is something you are trying to achieve.

I assume you have some reason to want to do this. FWIW, I personally think it is a bad idea.

Comment: 'reduced startup time' will merging reduce startup time?